# Giving HTML table cell priority over other cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a pretty simple table:

```
<table cellspacing=0 cellpading=0 border=0>
  <tr>
     <td width="50%">Here is column 1</td>
     <td width="50%">Here is column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way to have column 2 reduce width before column 1 does?  I'd like column 1 to stay as close to 50% as possible if the screen width becomes reduced.  If there is no further room for column 2 to collapse, however, then it is ok for column 1 to shrink.

I don't want to apply "white-space: nowrap" to column 1, apply a fixed with, or use javascript.  Is there any CSS solution?

Comment: If the 1st column is to remain 50%, what do you think percentage of the second column would be?

Comment: The idea would be for column 1 to behave as if it is "white-space: nowrap", but only until column 2 has shrunken as far as it can go.  At that point, it is ok for column 1 to start reducing width.

Comment: Why do I have a feeling you are using tables to layout non-tabular data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to give specific (non percentage) width to the first column (initial width can be calculated based on initial window size).

E.g.

**HTML**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpading="0" border="0">
  <tr>
     <td>Here is column 1</td>
     <td>Here is column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    font-size:40px
}

tr > td:first-child {
    width:280px;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/hyrvn/1/

Try resizing bottom-right window to the right.

Comment: That makes sense Yuriy.  Was hoping there was a different option, but that works fine.  :)  Thanks!